# Epimorphism of sheaves of rings

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, epimorphisms

$\newcommand{\fs}{\mathscr{F}}\newcommand{\gs}{\mathscr{G}}$Let ${\bf Sh}(X,{\bf Ring})$ be the category of sheaves of rings on $X$.

Let $\phi:\fs\to\gs$ be a morphism in ${\bf Sh}(X,{\bf Ring})$, and $\operatorname{im}\phi$ the image presheaf of $\phi$. Is it true that if $\phi$ is an epimorhism, then $\gs$ is the sheafification of $\operatorname{im}\phi$ ?

It would be true if we used ${\bf Ab}$ instead of ${\bf Ring}$, because ${\bf Ab}$ is a balanced category.

Comment: If $\phi$ is epimorphism, in which category: sheaves or presheaves?

Comment: $\phi$ is an epimorphism in the category of sheaves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false. Take $X = \{ \mathrm{p.t.}\}$ so that $\mathsf{Sh}(X,\mathsf{Ring})$ is actually just $\mathsf{Ring}$ and actually the image presheaf is a sheaf. But we know in $\mathsf{Ring}$ that $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is epic.